# Download a json content by accessing the url

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, wcf

This is my sample code. On execution, it gives the following error. "The remote name could not be resolved:www.javascriptkit.com". I have written this code in a WCF Service.

```
string url = "http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/javascriptkit.json";
Uri uri = new Uri(url);
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string output = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Is this written in any particular language?

Comment: @ScottHunter, tags improved :-)

Comment: This is C# code. I have a silverlight application which calls this WCF service method which should return the content. The content returned by the WCF method will be parsed and populated in a datagrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue is solved now. Added the below code in web.config within  tag. Thanks to all.

```
 <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

Comment: same solution Mouser suggests. Why you add your own answer and mark it correct. I give you negative remarks.

Answer (score 1):

Using this code in your `C#` code will make it work. It uses a webclient object to download the JSON in, then pass the contents of it to a JSON serializer. That serializer renders it to a dictionary object.

You'll need the following classes:

- `System.Web.Script.Serialization`
- `System.Web.UI.WebControls`

```c#
 var webClient = new WebClient();
 string readHtml = webClient.DownloadString("http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/javascriptkit.json");
 var a = new JavaScriptSerializer();

 Dictionary<string, object> results = a.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(readHtml);
 var title = results["title"].ToString(); //stores javascriptkit.com
```

For this to work in your WFC application add the following to your `web.config`:

```
<system.net>
   <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
   </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Comment: Your code also works. I just needed the 'readHtml' part in your code which gives the content of the mentioned url.  Rest of processing , I am handling in client side.  I had made my code working by adding a modification in web.config. But i will use this code as this appears less complicated. Thank you.

Comment: Whether we use HttpClient or WebClient, I needed to add the below code in web.config within tag to make this working. "The remote name could not be resolved:www.javascriptkit.com" is thrown.                                                                              <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>

Comment: @RakeshJ, that's a pity. I build my solution. (Not using WFC thought) and that worked. Will add your solution to mine to keep this as a valid alternative.